# Mongoid strange query result

Tags: mongodb, mongoid3

I'm using MongoDB through Mongoid with Rails 3 and observe this strange behavior when doing query in `rails console`:

```
> Table.where(:field => {"$exists" => true}).count
=> 3735
> Table.where(:field => {"$exists" => true}, :field => {"$ne" => ""}).count
=> 14878 # wtf???
> Table.where(:field => {"$exists" => true}, :field => "").count
=> 0 # at least it's not negative
> Table.where(:field => {"$exists" => false}).count
=> 11143
```

Since `11143 + 3735 = 14878`, I assume that `where(:field => {"$exists" => true}, :field => {"$ne" => ""})` also counts those records in which `:field` is not present (because `nil != ""`?). However, I believed conditions listed in `#where` would be joined with `and`, so it should match only those records where `:field` is not empty string AND is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "However, I believed conditions listed in #where would be joined with 'and'," but this is not correct.  The conditions are a hash, and you have a collision on the key :field.  Ruby silently uses the last value.

Please review the documentation for selection in Mongoid http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html, and use #and for a proper 'and' conjunction.  Note that you can #inspect your query and examine the returned Criteria object.  For example:

```
puts Table.where(:field => {"$exists" => true}, :field => {"$ne" => ""}).inspect
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Glad to help.  You can also see the query that is sent by Mongoid/Moped to MongoDB by checking the Rails log.